# iOS seems to be displaying a high bounce rate in Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics, ios9.2, ios9.3

I have an issue where Google Analytics shows just fine data for all other browsers but then for iOS (specifically version 9.3+), Google Analytics show a high bounce rate. Now I am very aware of the recent iOS bug however, Apple released a fix to this and yet, I still have these weird statistics.

Can anyone provide any clues or possibilities iOS is showing this kind of stat?

Comment: What does the page look like on iOS?

Comment: @Kara Thanks for your respose. The page is a typical eCommerce site however, the tracking was fine before until 2 weeks ago that the bounce rate became higher and no changes were made. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the page load time, and see if that's any different on iOS. Check the source report to see if iOS traffic is typical. Also, look at the volumes. If they're very low, you may be seeing warped results.

Another possibility is traffic from your own company; for sites with only a few hundred visitors a day, excluding internal traffic can have a noticeable effect on Bounce Rate, but since this is phone traffic it might be slipping through the filter.

Answer (score 0):

We actually tested this and it seems it's because of this: https://github.com/PierBover/ios-iframe-fix